# Next.js. How to call component's getInitialProps in Layout

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I add header component to layout but i don't want to send props from layout to header for every page I want use getInitialProps

layout.js

```
import Header from './header'
export default ({title}) => (
      <div>
        <Head>
          <title>{ title }</title>
          <meta charSet='utf-8' />
        </Head>

        <Header />

        {children}
      </div>
    )
```

header.js

```
export default class Header extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps () {
      const headerResponse = await fetch(someapi)
      return headerResponse;
    }
    render() {
        console.log({props: this.props})
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}
```

console: props: {}

App.js

```
  import Layout from './layout'
  import Page from './page'
  import axios from 'axios'

const app =  (props) => (
  <Layout >
    <Page {...props}/>
  </Layout>
)

app.getInitialProps = async function(){
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(someUrl)
    return response.data;

  } catch(e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
}

export default app
```

I want to use get initial props in Header component but it not firing

Comment: `getInitialProps` is only available at the top level of your application (page), however you can pass props inside your components

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: 2021 way of doing this :

```
// with typescript remove type if you need a pure javascript solution
// _app.tsx or _app.jsx
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';

import Layout from '../components/Layout';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  return (
    <Layout {...pageProps}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

// In order to pass props from your component you may need either `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`.
// You should definitely not do that inside your `_app.tsx` to avoid rendering your whole app in SSR;
// Example for SSR
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../data`)
  const data = await res.json()

  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } }
}
```

<del>Next.js uses the App component to initialize pages. You can override it and control the page initialization.</del>

<del>What you could do is, put your logic inside the `_app` override and pass it to your children components, example with a `Layout` component.</del>

<del>Create a `page/_app.js`</del>

```
import React from 'react'
import App, { Container } from 'next/app'

import Layout from '../components/Layout'

export default class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}
    

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    /* your own logic */

    return { pageProps }
  }

  render () {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

    return (
      <Container>
        <Layout {...pageProps}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

<del>There is a good example from zeit at [github](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/pass-server-data/pages)</del>

Comment: This is perfect I can use this as a kind of a global interceptor for getInitialProps() before every page render. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is helpful, but is outdated. 1- Container is deprecated. 2- getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) -> getInitialProps(ctx). 3- Component.getInitialProps(ctx) -> App.getInitialProps(ctx). For more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

Comment: What if I do not want to disable static-page generation on every single page in my app? I cannot use `getInitialProps` in my `_app.js` because Next will render every page with it... Let's say I have 2 layouts: `adminPanelLayout` and `blogLayout` and I want blog layout to be statically served and admin layout with `getInitialProps`

Comment: @Baterka I have updated my initial post with a 2021 way of doing this, Vercel team made a lot of improvement since my initial response. This is pretty trivial to do such a thing now without having to SSR ur whole app

Comment: let's say I have a component where I render a list of posts, I get list of post via fetch to API, and I need this list be updated on each page load, plus when I go to /post/38283 or /post/38726, there is another API call to get specific details by id, so I also need fresh data for that + need to inject headers before sending generated page to client side, what's the right way to handle this flow?

Comment: with `getServerSideProps` you could do exactly

Comment: What I read in Next.js documentation: "`App` currently does not support Next.js Data Fetching methods like `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`." That is in conflict with the answer. 
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats
@FabienGreard Can the answer be clarified, pls?